# click or select anywhere on the row to check the checkbox and highlight it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image]Hi I'm generating a table with toggle checkbox using Java Scripts I want to highlight if was being selected or being clicked how I could modify my code?

```
function draw_equipment($equipment)
{
    $equipment_name = $equipment['img_link'];
    echo "<div style='text-align:left;width:120%'>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' class='toggleCheckbox'>";
    echo "<img src='img/$equipment_name' alt='$equipment_name' width='120px'/><br/>";
    echo $equipment['equip_type'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use toggleClass on the checkbox and wrap it in a label to allow clicking on the image too.

I execute the change on load too in case the checkbox was already set to checked at the server or on reload

```js
$(function() {
    $(".toggleCheckbox").on("change",function() {
      $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("checked",this.checked);
    }).change(); // run at load too
});
```

```css
.checked { background-color:pink }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style='text-align:left;width:120%'><label><input type='checkbox' class='toggleCheckbox'><img src='https://logos.tlecdn.net/100x30/m_1203_marantz_7.png' alt='$equipment_name' width='120px'/></label></div>
<hr/>
<div style='text-align:left;width:120%'><label><input checked type='checkbox' class='toggleCheckbox'><img src='https://resources.sport-tiedje.com/bilder/ciclosport/ciclosport_t.gif' alt='$equipment_name' width='120px'/></label></div>
```

If you need to click on the WHOLE div to highlight, you need to add an event handler to the div but then you need to stopPropagation

```js
$(function() {
    $("div").has(".toggleCheckbox").on("click",function() {
      $(this).find(".toggleCheckbox").click();
    });
    $(".toggleCheckbox").on("click",function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation(); // this should not bubble to the div
    })
    $(".toggleCheckbox").on("change",function(e) {
      $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("checked",this.checked);
    }).change(); // run at load too
});
```

```css
div { background-color: #778899}
.checked { background-color:green }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style='text-align:left;width:120%'><label><input type='checkbox' class='toggleCheckbox'><img src='https://logos.tlecdn.net/100x30/m_1203_marantz_7.png' alt='$equipment_name' width='120px'/></label></div>
<hr/>
<div style='text-align:left;width:120%'><label><input checked type='checkbox' class='toggleCheckbox'><img src='https://resources.sport-tiedje.com/bilder/ciclosport/ciclosport_t.gif' alt='$equipment_name' width='120px'/></label></div>
```